# Codeigniter DB escape and like

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CI 3, and I have a problem using escape and like clause. Here is my code :

```
$where = '(a.title LIKE \'%'. $this->db->escape($name) .'%\' OR agi.senior_artist LIKE \'%'. $this->db->escape($name) .'%\')'
```

The problem is `$this->db->espace` add quotes to the string, so I got an error. It works without the escape, and only `$name` but I prefer to espace the data.

Is there a native solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
$this->db->escape_like_str()
```

instead

```
$this->db->escape()
```

when you use LIKE conditions

[Read more](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)

Comment: Oh nice ! I missed it in doc. Thanks !